# How does an airflow sensor work?

Tags: airflow, sensors, biomedical-engineering, drag, medical-devices

There are 4 piezoresistive sensors placed at position A, B, C and D.[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhaM.png)

I searched for the working principle of an airflow sensor and I saw this. If I am trying to identify the expected displacement directions of the beam locations at A, B, C and D when the airflow is in the positive x-direction, it seems that C and D will displace in the same direction and so do A and B. [image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDgs2.png)

Since the upper flow is clockwise, so C and D displace towards positive z-direction? And A and B displace towards negative z-direction due to the anti-clockwise flow? I wonder if I am understanding it correctly. Thanks!! [image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBsSu.jpg)

Comment: top picture is a different system from second picture ... top picture is like a joystick  ... air flow tilts the post

Comment: How does one particular airflow sensor work, or are you going to give us a list and ask about each?  There are probably a dozen different ways to measure airflow.